# Internal server error when sending an email using smtp

Tags: email, smtp, imap

I have a problem when I want to send an email using OpenCart using  a Linux Server with WHM and cPanel.

I set my OpenCart settings to send an email using SMTP. Sometimes the email is sent without problems, but after seconds or minutes I try to send another email and the problem appears.

Here is the problem part in a file: `/var/log/exim_rejectlog`

```
2022-01-20 09:20:14 dovecot_login authenticator failed for (mydomain.example) [my-ip]:49914: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=info@mydomain.example)
```

Here is the problem part in a file: `/var/log/maillog`

```
Jan 15 12:39:24 server dovecot: auth-worker(26974): Error: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=26967,uid=97): auth-worker<1>: dict(info@MYDOMAIN.example,111.11.111.11): Failed to lookup key shared/dovecot_userdb-smtp/info@MYDOMAIN.example: Connection closed: read(size=8192) failed: Connection reset by peer (reply took 0.000 secs (0.001 in dict wait, 0.000 in other ioloops, 0.000 in locks))
Jan 15 12:39:24 server spamd[16103]: spamd: connection from localhost [::1]:55828 to port 783, fd 5
Jan 15 12:39:24 server dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Aborted login by logging out (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<r4IOX53VaNp/AAAB>
Jan 15 12:39:25 server dovecot: lmtp(27023): Connect from local
Jan 15 12:39:25 server dovecot: lmtp(27023): Disconnect from local: Logged out (state=GREETING)
Jan 15 12:39:25 server dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<_cpanelserviceauthimap_gp9962dp53m_nh5z>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=27031, secured, session=<IgASX53VcIJ/AAAB>
Jan 15 12:39:25 server dovecot: imap(_cpanelserviceauthimap_gp9962dp53m_nh5z)<27031><IgASX53VcIJ/AAAB>: Disconnected: Logged out in=11, out=519, bytes=11/519
```

`info@MYDOMAIN.example` is my email which I use to send emails and `111.11.111.11` is my server IP.

Comment: "no auth attempts" is a clue to what is going on